# How to scrape data from Instagram page source?

Tags: php, python, web-scraping, instagram

I am new to all this. I work for a marketing company and I am looking to scrape data from our instagram influencer's in a more efficient manner.

I want to be able to scrape descriptions, number of posts, comments per post, likes, titles, etc. Having said that, I am new to programming and have absolutely no idea where to start, or which language would be best. Should I attempt to do this with Python, php, node? How do I get started? I know how to setup my working environment with python, with IDLE, but that's about it.

Thanks for the help.

tl;dr 
- new to programming 
- need help to scraping data from instagram

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I found great resource that you can use:
https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper

You need to learn about php before using it.
There is a guide on this page, so there is not much that you need to do from there, after you'll get around php.

Answer (score -1):

You may get any Instagram page's data by adding 'media' at the end of the page URL.

Example URL:

> https://www.instagram.com/dress_blouse_designer/media/

You may find a working code that scrapes **popular** images from an Instagram Page [here](https://runkit.com/vishnukanwar/scrap-an-instagram-page-s-popular-images)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. I am updating my response.